# Bounce Rate Calculation Query

Tags: seo, google-analytics, bounce-rate, session, bounce

A visitor comes to my site and stays on my home page for close to 2 mins and then leaves. This lead to a bounce. I am sure this would be happening with many visitors as my home page has got two videos and some content to engage the them. I have the following questions:

1. If a visitor has a one page session with x mins spent on it, will that still be considered as a bounce? Is there a time limit associated with one page sessions when analytics calculates bounce?
2. If there is no time factor into consideration for one page session while calculating bounce rate then is there a way by which I can reduce the bounce rate in this case?

Comment: Rather than rely on some amount of time on page, send Google Analytics "events" when the user interacts with your page.   Add events for playing video, pausing video, watching video to 80%, and scrolling down.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.. I implemented this to track user event for video "Play" and my bounce rate has come down to 60%. My another query is that  i have tracked this as an event in  analytics and set it as a goal. Correct me if I am wrong,  If i dont set it as a goal this will be seen as an event but does not setting it as a goal will affect the bounce rate ?

Comment: Just implementing the event will reduce your bounce rate.   You don't need it to be a goal for bounce rate purposes.    Goals are usually used for items that get people closer to converting (purchasing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this. Let's say that you built a one page site, which has a video on it. Then all one page sessions would be bounces. To avoid this, what you could do is that when the user is clicking something, or when the user is on the page for a certain time, you trigger an event in Google Analytics and add the non-interaction parameter in the FieldsObject array and set it to false.

Related documentation that will help you -

1. [Events in Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events)
2. [Non-interaction events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#NonInteractionEvents)